# How do I copy a two dimensional array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, string

I'm working with a program that uses two-dimensional arrays of Strings (probably not that smart to begin with, but eh), and I'd like to write a function that takes one of these arrays (let's say array1), makes an independent copy, and returns it (let's say array2). However, when I then change a value in array2, it seems to be reflected in array1.

My function currently looks something like this:

```
public static String[][] copy(String[][] matrix, int n) {
    String[][] out = new String[n+1][n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < n+1; j++) {
            if(matrix[i][j] != null) {
                String cp = new String(matrix[i][j]);
                out[i][j] = cp;
            }

        }

    return out;
}
```

I declare a new array of Strings, and then iterate through it, copying each value individually. When that didn't work, I even tried explicitly declaring a new string from each old string and putting that in the array instead.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Seems like it should work to me... can you provide some example code that illustrates the problem you've been having?

Comment: +1: works fine for me... can you provide the code for your whole test setup?

Comment: Is there an edit function? Sorry, all, I realized that the problem was actually with my print function. Thanks for your thorough help, though: I cleaned up the function with the suggestions and learned a lot about how Java passes arguments.

Comment: Actually, there is an edit function ... go ahead, find and use it :-) ...

Comment: Works for me. Provide a small, complete example of this not working, or it's not a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method looks like it should work, though passing in n as a parameter makes it brittle, using the input array's length field would be better, and you could even handle jagged arrays that way.

Making a copy of the contents is not necessary, since Strings cannot be changed - which leads to the main question: What kind of changes are you making that seem to be reflected in the copy? Show us the code that does this.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what the `n` parameter is for, but if I needed such a function, I'd use something like this:

```
public static String[][] copy(String[][] matrix) {
  String[][] copy = new String[matrix.length];
  for (int idx = 0; idx < matrix.length; ++idx)
    copy[idx] = matrix[idx].clone();
  return copy;
}
```

You don't need to create a copy of the `String`, because they are immutable. As pointed out by Michael in the comments, the `String(String)` constructor might be useful if the original string was created as a substring of some very large string. Another use is when you are using `String` objects as locks (not recommended), and want a private instance to avoid deadlocks.

Also, your check to see whether an element is null before assigning is unnecessary; if you have your loops setup correctly, the element is guaranteed to be null. (And if it's not, what's the harm in overwriting it?)

Comment: Another useful reason to use String(String) could be to force substrings of a large base String to be trimmed down so that the base String's memory can be reclaimed (since substring() usually keeps a reference to the entire base string)

Comment: Since String is immutable, you don't need to clone it.

Comment: @Michael: good point; will update accordingly. @Steve: no one is cloning any Strings. Could you explain what you are talking about?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [System.arraycopy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html). That way you can get rid of the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Arrays.copyOf](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)) would be of some use?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with your code : got exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

It's working for me, please try like this :

```
 public static String[][] copy(String[][] matrix, int n) 
 {
     String[][] out = new String[n][n];
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(matrix[i][j] != null) {
            String cp = new String(matrix[i][j]);
            out[i][j] = cp;
        }
       }
     return out;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question [Is Java pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) It can be a little confusing how Java passes objects, but this would explain why making a change to one array also makes the change to your other array.

Comment: -1 it doesn't explain, for the code given, why making a change to one array also changes the other.

Comment: Thats b/c the problem was not with the code given, re-read the first part of the question. From the question comments "I cleaned up the function with the suggestions and learned a lot about how Java passes arguments. – Lily"

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the 'n' parameter, as noted above is redundant, but also flawed by your code with n+1?? Your code would produce an ArrayIndexoutOfBoundsException if run something like:

```
String [][] m1 = { {"A", "B"}, {"C", "D" } };
String [][] m2 = copy(m1, 2);
```

Which presumably is how you intend it to be invoked?

It also limits your function to square 'matrices' of Strings. 
But as for the problem you cited, I see no reason why the program should behave that way... I even ran it using the above call (but with n=1???) then changed

```
m2[0][1] = "X";
```

and m1 was unaffected as expected.
Even replacing the innermost code line to:

```
out[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
```

does not change this, as the compiler rewrites it to what you originally had. In fact a lot of the String sytax is simply syntactic sugar for StringBuffers (such as concatenation and assignment). eg the compiler will rewrite

```
String s = "Hello ";
s += "World";        // Makes it appear that String is builtin type!
```

to

```
String s = new String("Hello ");
s = new StringBuffer(s).append("World").toString();
```

Which is why is you have lots of string concatenation inside loops they can perform very poorly.

I do not understand why you are having the problem you cited either.

And as you are not modifying the parameter 'matrix', 'Pass By Reference' has nothing to do with it.